How to override default configuration's phases with Selection Filter in the configSolver.xml?
Starting from the following configuration in configSolver.xml.
If I want to override this configuration by adding a filter selection class for the ChangeMove and SwapMove classes (AFAIK, a union of those 2 moves is used by default in the Local Search Phase, and a Cartesian product with ChangeMove for each planning value is used in the Construction Heuristics Phase) in this configSolver.xml, how should I proceed?
Should I have to reproduce the default config for those 2 phases, then overwrite it with the selection filter applied, or is there a better approach? I tried to do the following (at the moment it seems that it works properly, but I don't know if this is best practice):
<!--  Construction Heuristics generic config -->
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>ALLOCATE_ENTITY_FROM_QUEUE</constructionHeuristicType>
        <entitySorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY_IF_AVAILABLE</entitySorterManner>
        <valueSorterManner>DECREASING_STRENGTH_IF_AVAILABLE</valueSorterManner>
        <cartesianProductMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
            <!--  Apply the filter only for Timeslot planning value -->
                <filterClass>com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils.LessonChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
                <valueSelector variableName="timeslot"/>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <valueSelector variableName="room"/>
            </changeMoveSelector>
        </cartesianProductMoveSelector>
    </constructionHeuristic>

<!--    Late_Acceptance configuration-->
    <localSearch>
    <!-- Termination configuration -->
    <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <filterClass>com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils.LessonChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <filterClass>com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils.LessonSwapMoveFilter</filterClass>
            </swapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <!-- Acceptor and forager -->
    </localSearch>

    <!--    Tabu_Search configuration-->
    <localSearch>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <filterClass>com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils.LessonChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
                <filterClass>com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils.LessonSwapMoveFilter</filterClass>
            </swapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <!-- Acceptor and forager -->
    </localSearch>


Note that I have implemented the filters (for both ChangeMove and SwapMove) separately in a similar way to the examples from the documentation.
ChangeMove:
package com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils;

import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.score.director.ScoreDirector;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.decorator.SelectionFilter;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove;
import com.patrick.timetableappbackend.model.Lesson;
import com.patrick.timetableappbackend.model.Timeslot;
import com.patrick.timetableappbackend.model.Timetable;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;

public class LessonChangeMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<Timetable, ChangeMove> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LessonChangeMoveFilter.class);

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<Timetable> scoreDirector, ChangeMove changeMove) {
        Lesson lesson = (Lesson) changeMove.getEntity();
        Object planningValue = changeMove.getToPlanningValue();
        // Ensure the value is of type Timeslot
        if (!(planningValue instanceof Timeslot)) {
            return true; // Accept the move if the target value is not a Timeslot
        }
        Timeslot toTimeslot = (Timeslot) planningValue;
        return isMatching(lesson, toTimeslot);
    }

    private int calculateTimeslotDuration(Timeslot timeslot) {
        Duration duration = Duration.between(timeslot.getStartTime(), timeslot.getEndTime());
        return (int) duration.abs().toHours();
    }

    private boolean isMatching(Lesson lesson, Timeslot timeslot) {
        int timeslotDuration = calculateTimeslotDuration(timeslot);
        return (timeslotDuration == lesson.getDuration());
    }
}

SwapMove:
package com.patrick.timetableappbackend.utils;

import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.score.director.ScoreDirector;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.selector.common.decorator.SelectionFilter;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.SwapMove;
import com.patrick.timetableappbackend.model.Lesson;
import com.patrick.timetableappbackend.model.Timeslot;
import com.patrick.timetableappbackend.model.Timetable;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;

public class LessonSwapMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<Timetable, SwapMove> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LessonSwapMoveFilter.class);
    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<Timetable> scoreDirector, SwapMove swapMove) {
        Lesson leftLesson = (Lesson) swapMove.getLeftEntity();
        Lesson rightLesson = (Lesson) swapMove.getRightEntity();

        return isMatching(leftLesson, rightLesson);
    }

    private int calculateTimeslotDuration(Timeslot timeslot) {
        Duration duration = Duration.between(timeslot.getStartTime(), timeslot.getEndTime());
        return (int) duration.abs().toHours();
    }

    private boolean isMatching(Lesson lessonA, Lesson lessonB) {
        int timeslotDurationA = calculateTimeslotDuration(lessonA.getTimeslot());
        int timeslotDurationB = calculateTimeslotDuration(lessonB.getTimeslot());

        return (timeslotDurationA == lessonA.getDuration()) && (timeslotDurationB == lessonB.getDuration());
    }
}

EDIT: It seems that the above solution works pretty well, but I don't know if this is best practice to override the default configuration of Construction Heuristics and Local Search phases with Selection Filter since the quality of the scheduling problem's solution is slightly poorer than the default configuration with no Selection Filter.
Environment

Timefold Solver 1.9.0 Enterprise Edition
I set move-thread-count to AUTO (4 for my machine).
Java version is 21
Spring Boot 3.2.3


If I understand your filter correctly, you are making a filter so Lessons only get Timeslots of the correct length. This is a good use case for ValueRangeProvider on the Planning Entity.
To do this:

Remove the ValueRangeProvider annotation for Timeslot from the PlanningSolution class.

Add a method annotated with ValueRangeProvider on Lesson that return the List of Timeslots that can be assigned to the Lesson:


@PlanningEntity
public class Lesson {
    Timetable timetable; // Used to access possible timeslots
    // ...
    @ValueRangeProvider
    public List<Timeslot> getPossibleTimeslots() {
        return timetable.getTimeslots().stream().filter(this::matchesTimeslot).toList();
    }

    private boolean matchesTimeslot(Timeslot timeslot) {
        var timeslotDuration = Duration.between(timeslot.getStartTime(), timeslot.getEndTime());
        return (timeslotDuration.abs().toHours() == duration);
    }
}

With these changes, the filter can be removed from the SolverConfig (as each Lesson gets it own independent value range).
However, as noted in the docs, by limiting the value range of each Lesson, you are effectively creating a built-in hard constraint. This can have the benefit of severely lowering the number of possible solutions; however, it can also take away the freedom of the optimization algorithms to temporarily break that constraint in order to escape from a local optimum.

Thank you for your answer! I will try to implement ValueRangeProvider. Until then, can you please confirm if I implemented the Selection Filter in the correct way? After implementing the ValueRangeProvider, I will compare it with the Selection Filter to see what solution fits better into my problem.

Hello, Christopher! It seems that I can't use your implementation since it will require some changes in my code. This is how I implemented the Lesson Entity(https://github.com/PatrickDiallo23/Automatic-Timetable-Generation-System/blob/main/timetable-app-backend/src/main/java/com/patrick/timetableappbackend/model/Lesson.java). I am also using Spring JPA to communicate with the database. Can you give me some advice on how to adapt your code to my codebase or if I defined the Selection Filter in a proper manner?

In my case, Timetable is the PlanningSolution class.

The selection filter looks correct. To make the code I posted above work with JPA, I would add the Transient and JsonIgnore annotation to the Timetable field (which tells JPA the field is not part of the database, and Jackson to not serialize/deserialize that field). Then after creating the Timetable, I would set the timetable field on all Lesson instances (i.e., iterate through all the lessons in the timetable and set the field at the start of TimetableService.solve).

It seems a bit inefficient for my case compared to the Selection Filter approach (correct me if I am wrong), but I will consider your solution as well. I will also make a comparison between those 2 approaches in production. Thank you very much!

Each ValueRangeProvider list is cached (i.e. the list is only calculated once per entity). It does uses more memory as it has to store each list seperately. Swap moves also do additional checks in isMoveDoable (to prevent swapping a 1 hour lesson timeslot with a 2 hour lesson timeslot).
